# Determining lat_min, lat_max, lng_min and lng_max when width, height, center and zoom are known

Tags: openstreetmap

Given is a

```
width * height
```

pixels sized osm-div whose center coordinates are known.

Also the zoom level is known.

How do I figure out the lat_min, lat_max, lng_min and lng_max as a function of center_lat, center_lng, width, height and zoom that define the borders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has already been answered [here](http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/3099/calculate-bbox-from-latlonzoompixel-widthpixel-height) and probably [here](http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/11232/find-maxmin-lat-and-long).